# Are there things like an Android trigger

Tags: android, triggers, notifications

I have never developed something in Android before, but now my company has put me on a project which includes android.

My question is this: Is it possible to write an application that runs in the background and waits for triggers (if that is the correct word for it). For instance lets say I want my application to do something as soon as you open your emails or as soon as you get an email. Is there some API that I can use to interact with other applications such as Mail. The application does not have to have any GUI, it will literally just push some information notifications on the mail just received or opened.

I don't require a to technical answer, but rather just yes or no, and indeed yes, where can I get more info on it. Also if it is not possible, is there some workaround to achieve this. I have googled it, but most of the links are how to send an email from your application.

Thanks

EDIT: So it can even be triggered when a notification is received. Then I just want to look at the notification and determine if it is an email?

Comment: no, sorry. such mechanism in android would be using a broadcast, which exists for SMS, but there is no standard thing for emails.

Answer (score 0):

You could register BroadCastReceiver for the actions that you need to be caught

Comment: So I quickly had a look at BroadcastReceiver and found a [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/6sBMKpnraBw) that works with ContentObserver but google has since changed the [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/com/google/android/gm/contentprovider/GmailContract) and now all that I can get from the mail is: Label name, Total number of conversations, Number of unread conversations, Label text color and Label background color